# How to redirect two users according to their roles in PHP

Tags: php, database, types

How can I redirect two users according to their roles? I have database user type 1 and type 0. My log-in code is like this. Type 1 is suppose to be an admin and type 0 is a regular user.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);


if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)){
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
    } else {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if($hashedPwdCheck == false){
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
                header("Location: ../main.php?login=success");
                exit();
            }   
        }
    }
}
} else {
header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
exit();
}
```

Comment: For user type 1 and type 0 , make a if else header condition like 
 header("Location: ../main.php?login=success"); to if(type==1){ header("Location: ../main.php?login=success");}elseif(type==0){ header("Location: ../mainuser.php?login=success");}

Comment: So do you intend to redirect an admin to one page and a regular user to another page?

Comment: Are the user types stored in the users table.  I don't see this field?

Comment: What's stopping me from jumping into main.php and bypassing authentication?

Comment: Yes admin has different page and the user has another page, I have two tpes of users type 1 and type 0..... Please edit my code, I don't really know how to code I've just copy and paste from the internet.

Comment: Yes in the user table I've already set up type 1 as an admin and type 0 as an ordinary user..... I wanted type 1 to go to main.php and type 0 to go to user.php ....... How will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily by `if()..else...` but at all don't use directly `header` to redirect, I suggest you use this function to redirect:

```
function redirect($url){
    if (headers_sent()){
        die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href=\'' . $url . '\';</script>');
    }else{
        header('Location: ' . $url);
      die();
    }
}
```

this is what you need to do:

```
if($type == 1)
    redirect($admin_url);
else
    redirect($user_url);
```